# Change the backcolor of some properties of propertygrid control

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

[image: Propertygrid]

here as i have mentioned in the snapshot, i want to give any backgroundcolor to the mandatory property.
do we have anyway to achieve this.

Thank in advance!!!

Comment: As an alternative, put a `*` in display name of the field and also add a validation to the property to check value and throw an exception if value is null.

Comment: i have already added * in display name but can we change the * size and color?

Comment: No we can't. The feature you need, is a feature that is required for a data entry form and property grid is not designed for this goal. Why you need to use property grid this way? If using `*` is not enough for you, you can create your own object editor. For example you can simply use a `TableLayoutPanel` and show properties there in suitable controls and edit them.